# Sybase, create a new table from a select statment from multiple tables

Tags: sql, insert, sybase, union

I have two tables in Sybase:

`TABLE1`: holds the department data and emp_id associated with departments:

```
Dept_Id     Emp_id1   Emp_id2   Emp_id3
-------     -------   -------   -------
DEP1          11        22        33
```

`TABLE2`: holds the Emp_Id and multiple Address_Id associated with employee:

```
Emp_Id     Add_Id
------    --------
11         street1
11         street2
11         street3
22         mountRoad1
22         mountRoad2
33         PetersRoad
```

I want to join these two tables and insert the following results into a new table:

```
Dept_Id   Emp_Id   Add_Id
-------   ------   ------
DEP1       11       street1
DEP1       11       street2
DEP1       11       street3
DEP1       22       mountRoad1
DEP1       22       mountRoad2
DEP1       33       PetersRoad
```

How can I achieve this using single SQL query?

Comment: Employee Ids as columns, Really?

Comment: PS your table structures are pretty poor - having a column for each employee, and not having a sequence against your address lines...

Comment: Tbale1 and Table2 are existing table, I haven't created those. I want to insert records in Tbale 3 as mentioned above.Thanks

Comment: I tried with UNION and its works but my concern is performance, Table1 and Table2 are having huge amount of data. so what will be the better way to achive this??

Comment: Is the creation of table3 a one time thing or reoccurring?

Comment: A job will be run on monthly basis to insert the records in Table3 if record is not present already.

Comment: Is this [tag:sybase-asa], [tag:sybase-ase], [tag:sybase-iq], or [tag:sqlanywhere]? Trying to clean up the [tag:sybase] tag...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not use JOIN only:

```
insert into table3 (Dep_id,Emp_id, Add_id)
select table1.Dep_id, table2.Emp_id, Table2.Add_id
from table1 
join table2 on table1.Emp_id1=table2.Emp_id or table1.Emp_id2=table2.Emp_id or table1.Emp_id3=table2.Emp_id
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use UNION. For example:

```
Insert into Table 3 (Dep_id,Emp_id, Add_id)
select Dep_id,Emp_id1 as Emp_id, Table2.Add_id
from Table 1 
join Table2 on (Table1.Emp_id1=Table2.Emp_id)
union all
select Dep_id,Emp_id2 as Emp_id, Table2.Add_id
from Table 1 
join Table2 on (Table1.Emp_id2=Table2.Emp_id)
union all
select Dep_id,Emp_id3 as Emp_id, Table2.Add_id
from Table 1 
join Table2 on (Table1.Emp_id3=Table2.Emp_id)
```

PS: what if you need to add Emp_id4???? Your table structure is not normalized.

Comment: Thanks for the reply valex. There will be maximum of only three employee can be associated with one depatrment.

Answer (score 0):

If you're stuck with the silly structure for table1 then I'd probably create a view to artificially change the structure to a simple department, employee table. Something like this:

```
create view EmployeeDepartment
as 
    select Dept_Id, Emp_id1 as Emp_id from Table1
    union select Dept_Id, Emp_id2 as Emp_id from Table1
    union select Dept_Id, Emp_id3 as Emp_id from Table1
```

You can then use this view as required eg to select out department/employee/address

```
select e.Dept_Id, e.Emp_Id, a.Add_Id
from Table_2 a
join EmployeeDepartment e on e.Emp_id = a.Emp_id
```

Or to build your 3rd table

```
insert into table3 (Dep_id, Emp_id, Add_id)
select e.Dept_Id, e.Emp_Id, a.Add_Id
from Table_2 a
join EmployeeDepartment e on e.Emp_id = a.Emp_id
```

On the other hand its just as easy to sub query the views *select* to build your 3rd table

```
insert into table3 (Dep_id, Emp_id, Add_id)
select e.Dept_Id, e.Emp_Id, a.Add_Id
from Table_2 a
join (
    select Dept_Id, Emp_id1 as Emp_id from Table1
    union select Dept_Id, Emp_id2 as Emp_id from Table1
    union select Dept_Id, Emp_id3 as Emp_id from Table1) e 
on e.Emp_id = a.Emp_id
```

Certainly the view is more reusable if you have other scenarios and easier to maintain if you end up adding a 4th employee id (emp_id4). Other queries using the view wont need to change...